# iOS - Play mp3 before 4.0

Tags: ios, xcode, mp3

Im my app I play .mp3 files with the AVFoundation Framework (AVAudioPlayer), but this framework only exists in 4.0 or later; what can I use to play an mp3 before 4.0?

Comment: Maybe if you provided a code sample that would help. Also, why not just convert the mp3 to a more amenable format?

Comment: because I should create my app under 20 MB, in my app I have a lot of sounds, if I use another type my app go over 20 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking at [Apple's documentation for AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067) and it says at the top of that page:

> **Availability**   Available in iOS 2.2 and later.

I looked in one of my older (pre iOS 4) projects to see how I used to play sound files.  It was a combination of the AudioToolbox framework and some files from [Apple's older SpeakHere sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/).

Comment: but the AVFoundation Framework is available in iOS 4 and later :http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188 I don't understand

Comment: If I remember correctly, AVFoundation was somewhat extensively *revised* for iOS4 (for adding video editing capabilities, among other things), but it did exist before iOS 4.  And the AVAudioPlayer documentation that I linked to indicates the services apparently were available back in iOS 2.2.  BTW, do you have any iOS 3 or 2.X devices to test with?

Comment: the iOS simulator that comes with the 5.X SDK does allow you to simulator iOS 3.2.  Simply go under the "Hardware" menu and look for your choice of "Versions" (iOS versions, that is).

Comment: Oh, and one more thing.  If it's your boss (or client) who is telling you to make sure the app is compatible with iOS 2 or 3, keep in mind that people who don't take the time to upgrade to iOS 4 or 5 are the same kinds of people who don't like to pay for apps. Save yourself some time and headache and insist on sticking to more recent operating system versions (iOS 5 or at least iOS 4 & newer).